# Unexpected Web API routing when the URL ends in a forward slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using Web API 2 and am seeing unexpected routing behavior when the URL ends with a forward slash. My Web API config looks like this.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration webApiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        webApiConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        webApiConfig.EnsureInitialized();

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(webApiConfig);
    }
```

In WebApp.Start() I pass the url `http://host:port/configuration`.

I have two routes setup.

```
    [Route("~/")]
    public object GetResourcesList()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "Resource 1", "Resource 2", "Resource n" };
    }

    [Route("~/{resourceName}")]
    public object GetResource(string resourceName)
    {
        return "Resource " + resourceName;
    }
```

If I make a GET request to `http://host:port/configuration/` it calls `GetResourceList()` as expected.

If I make a GET request to `http://host:port/configuration` (no forward slash at the end) it calls `GetResource()` and returns "Resource configuration". I would expect it to the call `GetResourceList()`.

Why would it be calling `GetResource()` in the second example? And why would it pass configuration as the resourceName when WebApp.Start should be listening on `http://host:port/configuration` and not `http://host:port`?

I have also tried  `[Route("")]` and `[Route("{resourceName}")]` for `GetResourceList()` and `GetResource()` respectively and saw the same behavior.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

I also just tried listening on `http://host:port/configuration/` (with a slash at the end). No difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't messed with the OWIN self hosting stuff, but my guess is that it's listening on the URI you're providing but still passing in the entire URL, ie, the path that the Route picks up is not relative to the URI you're providing.

I would change your attribute routes from

```
[Route("~/")]
```

and

```
[Route("~/{resourceName}")]
```

to

```
[Route("configuration")]
```

and

```
[Route("configuration/{resourceName}")]
```

or use a route prefix of

```
[RoutePrefix("configuration")]
```

Comment: That throws an ArgumentException "The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character".  

Using tildes was more of a last ditch attempt. I did try [Route("")] which I think is the url equivalent of your suggestion.